# scrollable div implementation in react like in airtable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

Does anyone know how to implement this scrolling in react?

https://support.airtable.com/hc/article_attachments/360103336493/freeze_fields.gif

My goal is to show some extra space at the end of the div when a component is scrolled to the left